# MySQL update column value with max value from another column

Tags: mysql

I have a database with 2 tables:
"services" and "service_performance"
Those 2 tables have a SERVICE_ID column.

In "services" the SERVICE_ID values are unique (each service has a single ID/entry).
In "service_performance" there is an AVERAGE_MEMORY column with multiple entries per service_id

I am trying to update the MAX_VALUE column in "services" table with the highest AVERAGE_MEMORY value taken from the "service_performance" table.

I know my query is wrong because it throws an error:

## 1054 - Unknown column 'service_performance.SERVICE_ID' in 'where clause'

While 'service_performance.SERVICE_ID' does exist.

Here is my query:

```
   update _services
set MAX_VALUE = (SELECT MAX(AVERAGE_MEMORY) AS SERVICE_ID FROM service_performance)
where exists 
  (select *
  from services 
  where `services`.`SERVICE_ID` = `service_performance`.`SERVICE_ID`);
```

Comment: Does your table "Service_Performance" have a field named "SERVICE_ID" ?

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should find that this version works in MySQL:

```
update services s join
       (select service_id, MAX(AVERAGE_MEMORY) as maxmem
        from service_performance
        group by service_id
       ) sp
       on s.service_id = sp.service_id
    set s.MAX_VALUE = sp.maxmem;
```

Your version would work if it had the right table name in the `where` clauses:

```
update services
    set MAX_VALUE = (SELECT MAX(AVERAGE_MEMORY) AS SERVICE_ID
                     FROM service_performance
                     WHERE `services`.`SERVICE_ID` = `service_performance`.`SERVICE_ID`)
    where exists (select *
                  from service_performance 
                  where `services`.`SERVICE_ID` = `service_performance`.`SERVICE_ID`
                 );
```

I am assuming that `update _services` is a typo and should really be `update services`.

Comment: thanks to everyone. I did get it to work with that second version (and yes I had a typo when I typed my query here with an extra _

Answer (score 0):

MySQL is complaining because in this query there is no `service_performance` table

Try it like this:

```
   UPDATE _services s INNER JOIN service_performance p
   ON s.SERVICE_ID=p.SERVICE_ID
   SET s.MAX_VALUE=MAX(p.AVERAGE_MEMORY) GROUP BY p.SERVICE_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a database to test on, but firstly you haven't given the subquery an alias, so it doesn't know what service_performance.Service_ID is.

Secondly, in this context the subquery needs to return a single value rather than a table, so you may not be able to reference it. If adding the alias to the subquery doesn't work, then something like the following should work:

```
update _services
set MAX_VALUE = (SELECT MAX(AVERAGE_MEMORY) AS SERVICE_ID FROM service_performance
                 INNER JOIN
                 services
                 on services.SERVICE_ID = service_performance.SERVICE_ID)
```